# WPF XAML TextBlock Send Content to New Line

Tags: c#, xaml, line, new-operator, textblock

I have a TextBlock, like this one:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBlock Name="PatchNotesTxt" Width="291" Height="226" Style="{StaticResource PatchNotes}">
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test TEST
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But the problem is that when the content reaches the end of the TextBlock it isn't transfered to a new line. How am I supposed to achieve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `TextWrapping` property of the textbox to `Wrap`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [TextWrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping.aspx) property on the TextBlock.
`<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>`